# Incomplete value passed with autocomplete (jquery)

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have a form input which uses a jquery autocomplete function#1:

```
$( function() {
    var availableTags = JSON.parse($('#possible_options').val());
    $( "#id_form1" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
} );
```

Working almost perfectly fine: once you start writing, the dropdown appears with the expected possible values. When one of the dropdown values is selected, the value selected appears in the form input box and an event is triggered:

```
$('.form-control').on('change autocompleteselect',function () {
    var query1; 
    query1 = $('#id_form1').val();
    $.get('/suggest/', {selection1: query1}, function (data) {
        $('#resultstable').html(data);
    });
});
```

This function#2 gets the value in the form (once autocomplete has finished or the value in the form has changed) and updates a results table. **Here comes the problem**: when you start typing a few letters in the form input, and then you select a value from the dropdown (triggering function#2 when the value is selected), function#2 instead of getting the selected value,gets just the string of letters typed so far, and therefore occasions a problem when updating the table.

I've been trying different workarounds with no luck.
Thank you very much,
Carlos

Comment: You failed to show us what `/suggest/` returns. If I had to guess - you probably neglected to properly _quote_ attribute values in the HTML code you are returning from that endpoint.

Comment: Say I get to the form, where I have to put the US city I live in. I start writing _wash_, and washington appears in the dropdown. I select it, and the selected value then appears in the input box, and function#2 is called. Which sends a GET request to the server to update the table values:
GET /suggest/?city=wash HTTP/1.1" 200 85
The problem is, that it doesn't send the selected value, but just the string that was typed in.

Comment: Show us the server-side code for that part.

Comment: Have you verified that `$('#id_form1').val()` does indeed return what you think it does?

Comment: Following the above example, $('#id_form1').val() returns _wash_. That's what I have to solve, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the selected value then you can use either `autocompletechange` or `autocompleteselect` or both based on the code below.

`autocompletechange` event is triggered when you select an option and blur out of the input field.

`autocompleteselect` event is triggered after immediately after selecting an option.

```
$('#id_form1').on('autocompletechange autocompleteselect', function (e, ui) {
    console.log('You selected: ' + ui.item.value);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If I assign ui.item.value to query1, instead of $('#id_form1').val(), works like a charm. Thank you very much!